# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, jvm, initialization

I am getting following error frequently in eclipse IDE 3.2, how could I save the application from these OutOfMemory?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1814)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:872)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:75)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1325)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:289)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:111)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2101)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1325)
    com.mfic.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    com.mfic.dao.BaseHome.getSession(BaseHome.java:16)
    com.mfic.core.helper.UserManager.findByUserId(UserManager.java:248)
    com.mfic.core.action.Login.authenticate(Login.java:39)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331641/eclipsejava-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space)

Comment: @You marked this as a duplicate of the three years younger question. Better change your target.

Answer (score 36):

If you are getting the questioned error in the secondary Eclipse Application, adding `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`  in `ini` won't help. You need to go into `debug or run configuration->arguments` and add that piece in VM arguments.I also increased others memory limits so:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms120m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

It helped.

Edit. After some experiments I've found, that Eclipse does take memory limits from the ini file. But... it does it only once, at the creation of a new workspace. Parameters from -vmarg in eclipse.ini create the default VM parameters line. So, if you are working on the existing workspace, change debug or run configuration. But change eclipse.ini, too, for better future.

Comment: `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` is more than enough.

Comment: @pro_cheats There was one guy already who told that 640k memory is enough for everything... Don't think that the whole world is limited to your tasks.  We are talking on writing wizards - launching application in Eclipse launched in Eclipse. Even in 2012 512M was definitely not enough. Now Eclipses became bigger and it could take even more memory.

Comment: `-Xms120m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` works

Answer (score 20):

Your project eats a lot of memory. Give Eclipse more memory to work with. Edit `eclipse.ini` to modify or add the following lines below `-vmargs`.

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Assuming you've at least 2GB of RAM.

#### See also:

- [Editing `eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Comment: It seems like your solution is only a temp solution, how to fix the underlaying problem, and use less permgen space?

Comment: @Grae: profile the code and improve it. If it cannot be improved and those memory allocations are simply mandatory in order to run your code, then just give it more memory. Simple as that.

Answer (score 19):

- Click on Server instance.
- Open Launch Configurations.
- Increase memory to JVM,in argument tab.

### -Xms64m -Xmx256m

See below images:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Java applications are allowed to use only limited amount of memory. The exact amount of memory your particular application can use is specified during the application startup. To make things more complex, the Java memory is separated to different regions, one of which being called PermGen.

Size of all those regions is set during the JVM launch. If you do not explicitly set the sizes, platform-specific defaults will be used.

So – the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` message indicates that the **Permanent Size area in memory is exhausted**.

This specific area called PemGen is a dedicated region where Java classes are loaded and stored. This consists of the following:

- Names of the classes
- Fields of the class
- Methods of a class with the bytecode of the methods
- Constant pool information
- Object arrays and type arrays associated with a class
- Just In Time compiler optimizations

That’s pretty much it. Some more bits and pieces, but it does not impact the actual memory consumption by more than few percent. All these are allocated in the permanent generation and stay in the permanent generation.

As you can see, the permanent generation size requirements depend both upon the number of classes loaded as well as the size of such class declarations. So it is easy to see the main cause for such error: either **too many classes or too big classes are being loaded to the permanent generation**.

Quick fix for symptoms is easy - if we have exhausted the PermGen area in the heap, we need to increase its size. This solution is indeed helpful if just have not given your JVM enough elbow room. So alter your application launch configuration and add (or increase if present) the following:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: why 512m? Is there any reason why many examples give that size?

Answer (score 2):

This happens pretty frequently when running Tomcat inside Eclipse during debug sessions etc. From memory, it's an issue with the Sun JVM. Annnyway, there's an easy fix:

Just add the following below your -vmargs in eclipse.ini (which is in the same directory as your eclipse binary):

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

This will enable a more aggressive garbage collection while running Eclipse, and is a more elegant solution than just throwing more RAM at Eclipse.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The answers above probably solve it for you, but here are some interesting relevant links anyway:

Here is an article with a lot of discussion and suggestions about this error:
http://www.jroller.com/agileanswers/entry/preventing_java_s_java_lang

Discussion of an example of how a Permgen OOM error can occur:
http://blogs.oracle.com/fkieviet/entry/classloader_leaks_the_dreaded_java

Here is an actual solution, posted on StackOverflow recently.
It is for Tomcat but may be useable in Eclipse:
[Dealing with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88235/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space-error)

Answer (score 1):

Increase your `MaxPermSize` in your `eclipse.ini`. I suggest setting it to 128M or 256M if you're confortable with RAM

```
-vmargs -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
```

Also note that lots of people faced PermGen problems with Eclipse 3.2 as reported in [Perm-Gen Errors Got You Down?](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t77021.html). And since Eclipse 3.2 is more than 4 years old, I'd suggest upgrading to a more recent version (Eclipse 3.6 is the current version).

#### References

- [FAQ How do I increase the permgen size available to Eclipse?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)

Answer (score 1):

And also after trying the above options, please check with updated JVM.
I was using jdk1.6 and faced the same problem.
When I changed the jvm in eclipse to JDK1.7, it is working fine.