# Eclipse 3.5.2 Classic Error

Tags: java, eclipse

When I start  a Java modelling project I get this error:

> error instantiating ecore package http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process
>   permgen space

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible solution here would be to increase your permagen space (which is different from your regular *heap*). In the case of Eclipse, it implies changing your eclipse.ini file which lies in the Eclipse root directory by adding:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
```

A [lot of Eclipse users seem to have the same problem](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171585&start=0) so reading the posts there might help your cause in case the above suggestion doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use virtual eclipse machine, ini settings won't help. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814631/715269) for the answer.