# Eclipse throwing PermGen Space errors

Tags: android, eclipse

My Eclipse helios has been throwing weird `PermGen space` and `Java Heap` errors since the time I've got this new HDD, put new OS into it and have re-installed Java.

Does anyone have a guess why this is happening?

I followed [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171585&start=0), [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse?) and [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?) as well but adding anything into `eclipse.ini` just won't work. The only way I could get it to work was to start eclipse from command line with specific parameters.

I am running on windows 7 as of now.

here's my `eclipse.ini` I've added some things into it after going through the above links:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

**EDIT**

Here are the screenshots of the errors that I am receiving, even after correcting the ini file:

[image: First error]

[image: second error]

[image: Third Error]

[image: Fourth Error]

And here it finally asks if I would like to exit the workbench. If I choose not to, then nothing works.

[image: Fifth Error]

Sorry for flooding this question with images, but I felt they'll help.

Comment: Could you post your `eclipse.ini`?

Comment: I've posted the contents in the question

Answer (score 1):

You have two -vmargs.  You should only have one, combining the two fields.  Ie:

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=512M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

The extra `-vmargs` will be passed from the launcher to the JRE and so it's fairly platform dependent as to what happens.  On my Apple/Sun JRE with Eclipse 3.7, it's ignored.  On my Sun JRE with Eclipse 3.7 on Windows, it errors immediately.  It's possible that there's a setup that ignores everything after the invalid parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just try this out on my Windows and will post the results back. Currently I am on a mac, where things just work :)

Comment: I applied your changes, but still no effect. I posted the screenshots of the errors in the question. I hope they'll help

Answer (score 1):

The screenshots are not very useful. They all just complain about permgen and head space in different ways. Here's my `eclipse.ini` (Windows 7 64-bit, 32-bit Java, JDK 1.7.0):

```
 -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
 -showsplash
 org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256m
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 -vmargs
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx384m
```

Have you checked the actual Eclipse command line? Open the task manager and make sure that you have "Command Line" selected in "Select columns". My command line looks something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe" ... -Xms40m -Xmx384m ... -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ...
```

If the options are not present, then you (unsurprisingly) have a problem with the Eclipse launcher. If the options are in place and you still get the permgen/heap space problems, then you probably have a memory leak of some sort. Your best shot is to use a tool like JVisualVM to figure out where the problem lies.

Not all problems with heap and permgen space are caused by too small limits being passed to the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. I'll try this out as soon as I am home. moreover, should I provide with some sort of error log so that the errors are understandable?

Comment: Well, if you are getting permgen and/or heap space errors, there is not very much more information about the errors themselves which is useful.

Answer (score 0):

No changes in ini file had helped me. JesperE's variant won't worked. But you could set variables in VM arguments as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814631/715269)