# JBoss : outOfMemory PermGen space

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am using jboss 6.0, eclipse indigo

I changed JBOSS_Home/bin/run.conf.bat

but in console while server is starting it says

VM Arguments: bla bla -XX:MaxPermSize=256m bla bla

but in run.conf.bat it is -XX:MaxPermSize=512 m

where can i change vm arguments, in jdk installation directory?

thanks

---

**SOLVED**

in eclipse double click on server, options editor comes, change vm arguments.

this arguments overrides run.conf.bat

Comment: I don't know the answer, but once you find out, you can also try to add `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` which may help too.

Comment: You should not put the answer in the question. You should post an answer. 48h after the question is been asked, you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the eclipse virtual machine doesn't take memory limits from the ini file. It is **very** strange, but it is so. look for the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814631/715269)

Edit. After some experiments I've found, that it takes memory limits from the ini file. But does it only once, at the creation of a new workspace. Parameters from -vmarg in eclipse.ini create the default VM parameters line.

Answer (score 0):

> but in run.conf.bat it is `-XX:MaxPermSize=512 m`

It seems you have space between `512` and `m`. Can you try to remove the space? My `run.conf.bat` also has uppercase `512M`(instead of `512m`). Since I'm using OSX/Linux I don't know if that matter for Windows.