# Tomcat doesn't start in Eclipse with "Exception in thread "main"

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

In Eclipse Tomcat doesn't start with error message "'Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem. Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.".  In the console the last output is `Exception in thread "main"`.

When removing all projects from the server, Tomcat starts fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a memory related problem.  It can be misleading since there is no `Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` shown in the console.  The only way to get a hint about a memory issue is opting for "Debugging" when running the server.  You then get the familiar [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743992/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space) error.

To solve the problem increase the memory for Tomcat in Run configurations -> *Your Tomcat Server name* -> Arguments tab and then add `-Xms120m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` in the VM arguments.