# Is running eclipse in debug mode takes more memory then in "normal" mode?

Tags: java, eclipse

Well, the title is self - explenationary...

I have a heavy app that gives me OutOfMemoryException on debug mode (and I allredady reached maximum memory allowed in eclipse.ini), is there a chance it will flow on "standard" mode?

Comment: The memory space in eclipse.ini is just for Eclipse, use the 'Run Configuration' for you app to set the memory for the application.

Comment: Of course. The debugger consumes quite a few system resources. Just go ahead and try it. But you should also consider to lighten your app a little bit

Comment: @ZerO can you give me example to which resources?

Comment: @Alaychem what kind of details?

Comment: Increase the MaxPermSize in server's argument.
[check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743992/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-permgen-space

Comment: @JagannathSabat - your answer is a "how-to" for greg answer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, for verifying you can open task manager or do top for that process id. Considering you can't lighten up the app try to close all other heavy weight application whilst your debugging.