# Eclipse crashes with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, tomcat6

The generated error is

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:183)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:576)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:546)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:477)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:465)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:445)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:381)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:457)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.RenameAction.<init>(RenameAction.java:57)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.RefactorActionGroup.<init>(RefactorActionGroup.java:350)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.actions.RefactorActionGroup.<init>(RefactorActionGroup.java:197)
at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorRefactorActionProvider.init(JavaNavigatorRefactorActionProvider.java:58)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.initialize(NavigatorActionService.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.getActionProviderInstance(NavigatorActionService.java:355)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.NavigatorActionService.fillActionBars(NavigatorActionService.java:253)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager.selectionChanged(CommonNavigatorManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2132)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleSelect(CommonViewer.java:483)
```

The content of eclipse.ini

```
 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize=512M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize=512M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I found some solution on this error and implemented it accordingly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16810832/5031486

https://stackoverflow.com/a/88262/5031486

After implementing the solution provided in above link still I'm getting this error and Eclipse still crashes.

I am using Eclipse Galileo, JDK 1.7, Apache tomcat 6.0.

Changes made in eclipse.ini file

```
    -Xms40m -Xmx512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Previous values were

```
    -Xms40m -Xmx128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

I have made above changes. But still i have same problem.
Can any one help me with this.

Comment: Please watch your grammar more closely. If your question is hard to read due to bad grammar, you won't get answers. Please avoid chat abbreviations for the same reason.

Comment: Can you pls add the exact changes you have made?

Comment: @soilworker I have mention the changes Please check it

Comment: What exactly is failing? Is it Eclipse itself? A program you are running? Tomcat?

Comment: As you mentioned tomcat in your post, where does the OOME happens exactly?

Comment: @greg-449 eclipse crashes automatically after 4 to 5 minutes with the mentioned error

Comment: Show us the exact contents of your eclipse.ini file

Comment: @greg-449 I have provided eclipse.ini content. Please check the problem explanation

Answer (score 1):

Your eclipse.ini is a mess with all sorts of duplication. Try something like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```