# GC overhead error occurs after making a full publish on jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

This error only occurs when the project is published. When I start the server There is no error. Also I changed the Xms and Xmx values in Eclipse.ini as I have been told. But noting happens.

Console:

```
14:32:16,757 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MIS.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MIS.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "MIS.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to index deployment root for annotations
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:88) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: `eclipse.ini` has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880255/out-of-memory-error-starting-jboss-with-portal-from-eclipse